# QTextEdit how to modify stylesheet elements from C++

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtextedit

I'm looking for the fastest way to modify css style for body element inside QTextEdit instance.

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
ui->textEdit->setStyleSheet("body {background-color: #aaa}");
```

I need a method that would update internal css stylesheet of the html document open inside QTextEdit.

Comment: that is the right way, just get the css right.

Comment: Whats wrong with css here ? lack of ; after color definition ? If I use it like this  ui->textEdit->setStyleSheet("background-color: #eee; "); it works ok but html code of the document is not updated. It seems that setStyleSheet only modifies temporary widget parameters.

Answer (score 2):

setStyleSheet updates the style sheet of the widget itself, not of the HTML document which is displayed by the text edit. As a QTextEdit does not have a "body" part, the line is ignored.

If you want the HTML document to use a different style sheet, you would have to modify the displayed HTML content (or rather the hidden stylesheet include line) directly

Answer (score 1):

You are using the correct member function `QWidget::setStylesheet()` if you need examples on how to apply the proper Stylsheet, Qt has some examples [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qlineedit)

Comment: Thx. But know I think that this method sets a stylesheet for the widget and has nothing to do with html document inside editor :) Maybe i'll  modify html directly.

Comment: Yes, it has nothing to do with the contents of the QTextEdit. This is the stylesheet for _the_ widget and how it draws itself